# Why does typeof operator shows different output without parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, typeof

Consider the following code:

```js
console.log(typeof ('6'/'2')) // => "number"
```

Now if I remove the parenthesis after `typeof`

```js
console.log(typeof '6' / '2') // => NaN
```

which shows a different output. I'm wondering how JavaScript engine is working here.

Comment: If removing parentheses changes the outcome, it is most likely caused by [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 5):

`typeof '6'` returns `'string'`.

When you remove the parenthesis, the condition becomes `'string' / '2'`, which is `NaN`.

If you keep the parenthesis, the number division is done first, then `typeof` is called on the number.

Answer (score 1):

Because the code in parentheses executes first, So in the first statement will output  `2`, and the typeof 2, is `number`

But in the second statement, it will get `typeof '6'` first, which equal to `string`, then will do a dividing operation, which will equal to `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` is an [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#unary_operators).

> A unary operation is an operation with only one operand.

`typeof '6'` is processing the string '6' and then divided by '2' which results in NaN ('string' / '6'). While `('6'/'2')` is calculated and casted to a number.